# Want to route to base controller if specified controller is not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have a Base controller which providers basic implementations of some actions:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BaseAppController : Controller
{...
```

I have several controllers that derive from this and they are called using the routing from the base controller. They add various functionality. For example:

```
public class SomeController : BaseAppController
{
... more stuff ...
}
```

Now when the request goes to

> http://appurl/Some/MyAction

it obviously uses the MyAction which is either in the SomeController or in BaseAppController.

What I want to achieve is that if I send a request to:

> http://appurl/NonExistent/MyAction

I want it to determine that NonExistentController doesn't exist and revert to using the BaseAppController instead.

Any pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FilterAttribute to redirect response with 404 Not Found status code to different url / route.

Once you created the filter register it in FilterConfig.cs

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new MyNotFoundAttribute());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch NonExistent controllers or methods through Webapiconfig.cs in App_start folder.

Append below code to Webapiconfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ResourceNotFound",
routeTemplate: "{*uri}",
defaults: new { controller = "BaseApp", uri = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

This should catch all not found api request and send to BaseAppContoller.